# Example of function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ continuous at $x$ iff $x$ is trascendental

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I've seen examples of functions that are continuous only at the irrationals, and discontinuous at the rationals, and I wanted to go a bit further, but I couldn't come up with a function like the one in the title.

Does anyone know such an $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{a_n\}$ be the set of algebraic real numbers. Define
$$
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
\frac{1}{n} & \text{if} & x=a_n,\\
0 & \text{if} & \text{$x$ is transcendental}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Check that $f$ is continuous at $x$ iff $x$ is transcendental.